# BizTalk: Send Ports not showing up in the deployed orchestration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2010, send-port

I am trying to deploy a simple orchestration with 1 Receive port and 1 Send port. When I am trying to deploy the solution from Visual Studio 2010 only Receive port is appearing in the Administration Console for binding but the Send port is not showing up at all.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

BizTalk version : 2010

The issue is with the Scope shape. I am using the Send Port inside the Scope shape, now when I am deploying the application, the Send port is not available in the Orchestration for binding. Orchestration is showing only 1 Receive port and no Send port. Please guide how to use Send port inside a Scope shape.

Answer (score 3):

If Binding setting on the logical port (the Port shape in Orchestration) is set the Specify Later or Direct then no physical port will be created.  However you can create the ports manually in the Admin console and bind the Orchestration to port.

If it is configured to Specify Now or Dynamic, it will create the port (but with quite horrid names).

Most developers I know will use the Specify Later or Direct and create the ports in the Admin console and then create binding files to use as part of the release & dev setup process rather than rely on the deploy from Visual Studio to create the ports except for the Dynamic ports when it is easier to let that happen.

Comment: Explained the issue in the edited version, the Send port apprearing inside a Scope shape is not available for Binding in the orchestration after deployment. Please advice.

Comment: If it is a Direct port, then there will be no logical port shown in the Admin console as that publishes to the message box and you need to have subscriptions for the messages.  e.g. Having a subscription on the send port that looks for either the type of message or promoted properties in the message.

Answer (score 2):

I just have faced the same problem, it's definitely a VS bug. I moved the orchestration from one project to another, and after recompilation, all logical send ports of the orchestration disappeared in BizTalk Admin Console.

Fortunately, if you just remove one of the send ports, and create it again(reusing the existing port type), then after deployment you will get back your send ports.